How to update data in kotlin's paging with 100 temporary data first and then only the part of the data that is displayed
Is there a way to update the data in kotlin paging with 100 temporary data first and then only the part of the data that is displayed?
After preparing 100 temporary data, we can get 100 normal data by sync and update them, but that would be a waste of processing, so we would like to update and describe only the displayed part of the data.
Is there such a function in PAGING?
If I put fake data into uiState at first and then run the actual data acquisition process, 100 temporary data will be lost.
I want to keep the total number of data displayed as 100.
class PagingSourceViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val moviesRepository: MoviesRepository
) : ViewModel() {
data class UiState(
val pagingDataFlow: PagingData\<Movie\> = PagingData.empty(),
val isLoading: Boolean = false,
val errorMessage: String? = null
)

    // UiStateを保持するStateFlow
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(UiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<UiState> = _uiState
    private val intList = Array(100) { it }
    private val startPosition = 99
    fun load() {
        // 最初に仮データを設定
        loadFakeData()
    
        // 実際のデータを後から取得
        fetchMovies()
    }
    
    private fun loadFakeData() {
        // 仮データとして100件を設定
        val fakeMovies = List(intList.size) { index ->
            Movie(
                id = index.toLong(), title = "Fake Movie $index",
                description = "description",
                cardImageUrl = MoviePagingSource.IMAGE_URL,
                backgroundImageUrl = MoviePagingSource.ALTERNATE_IMAGE_URL,
            )
        }
    
        // 仮データをPagingDataに変換して送信
        _uiState.update {
            it.copy(
                pagingDataFlow = PagingData.from(fakeMovies),
                isLoading = true,
                errorMessage = null
            )
        }
    }
    
    private fun fetchMovies() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // 実際のデータを取得（例えばAPIから）
            moviesRepository.getMovies(startPosition = startPosition, intList = intList).collectLatest { pagingData ->
                
                // 実際のデータで更新
                _uiState.update {
                    it.copy(
                        pagingDataFlow = pagingData,
                        isLoading = true,
                        errorMessage = null
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


So you want to always have 100 items loaded in your paging, start with all fake data and then, as user scrolls the list, you want to gradually replace the fakes with real data? Do I understand correctly?

Yes, that is correct.

You can probably achieve this with placeholders. You have to enable them in the paging config first:
Pager(
  config = PagingConfig(
    pageSize = 10,
    initialLoadSize = 20,
    prefetchDistance = 10,
    enablePlaceholders = true,
  ),
  initialKey = null,
  ...
)

then in your PagingSource, you have to always return correct itemsBefore and itemsAfter count:
override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Data> {
  val page = params.key

  if (page == null) {
    // at first, return empty data with itemsAfter = 100,
    // so you immediately get 100 placeholders without delay
    return LoadResult.Page(
      data = emptyList(),
      prevKey = null,
      nextKey = 1,
      itemsBefore = 0,
      itemsAfter = 100,
    )
  } else {
    // then you always load current page and count correct value for
    // itemsBefore and itemsAfter
    val data = loadPage(page) // todo: handle loading errors...
    return LoadResult.Page(
      data = data,
      prevKey = if (page == 1) null else page - 1,
      nextKey = page + 1,
      itemsBefore = (page - 1) * params.loadSize,
      itemsAfter = 100 - page * params.loadSize,
    )
  }
}

With this, you should get paging list that will always have 100 items, but those that are not yet loaded will be null - you display your fake data there.

val data = loadPage(page) and using restApi to retrieve it would result in an error.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method jp.ne.androidtv.presenter.CardPresenter.getPresenter, parameter item
    at jp.ne.androidtv.presenter.CardPresenter.getPresenter(Unknown Source:6)
    at androidx.leanback.widget.ItemBridgeAdapter.getItemViewType(ItemBridgeAdapter.java:297)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6367)
    at


well my code checks that page is not null before it's used, so this error is somewhere in your code...

CardPresenter.
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: Presenter.ViewHolder, item: Any) to
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: Presenter.ViewHolder?, item: Any?) and the error no longer occurs.
Thanks.
It seems to be working fine.

Good to hear. If it works for you, you can accept the answer :)
